# Calling another class's property within a particular class's method causing an overflow Error.

Tags: c#, class, oop, stack-overflow

So I have two classes. 
One called 'Indexers' where I store the following strings:

```
  class Indexes
{
    public string IndexAlpha = "4uCLD[mY7^&*F_5+tXc~UrHMv1ZRxy|`3V}sjIOP<g#wT,.lnG6aK9/SJz?]bB$:8{2hfq=-0N()kd%iAe;'QEp!@>Wo"; //
    public string IndexOmega = "iHL@C7(^nYzu?4$5-<cJKe~;b/XAPF_[Uf&{|m9Oolg#%]xM0REyW`jN':82Q=p6}h3kwGTZ1Vt>v,DsS.!daBri)q+*";//                                                                                                                                  //
    public string EncryptionCharLibrary = ",q@xRm|T=3`adV!.sDZMi)h8tb1;eKy7Yn^Q2Gwk0S]?~HL(}$4Op#g6NjU<-fAilE:%9/J[Xv>{P&zW'co+Cu5_FrB*";// 
}
```

The other is called 'Persons' where I am running the following method..

This is called first (within the 'Persons' class):

```
 Indexes UsingIndex = new Indexes();
```

Then later... v

```
    public string InitialEncryptionComputationAndRepeatTracker() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Password);
      int   count = ForMethod.ComputeOddEven();
        while (PasswordLength > 0)
        {

            char toFind = PasswordAsArray[PasswordLength - 1];//find first Password Char in array[0] to start                 
            int FromAlpha = 0;
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                FromAlpha = UsingIndex.IndexAlpha.IndexOf(toFind);
            }
            else
            {
                FromAlpha = UsingIndex.IndexOmega.IndexOf(toFind);

            }
            char FromOmega = UsingIndex.EncryptionCharLibrary[FromAlpha];
            //TEST a Character:  
            //MessageBox.Show("input: " + toFind + " | High/low: " + FromAlpha + " | Encryption: " + FromOmega);
            char[] squiggle = { '-' };
            if (toFind != squiggle[0])
            {
                //do nothing (subtract 1 from length down below. --v-- 

                sb[PasswordLength - 1] = FromOmega;                         // store in position of StringBuilder  -
                FinalEncryptedPass = sb.ToString();              //  Enter change into password value    -                                                                                                        <-1

                //Checkfor repeat values -v- 
            }
            int RepeatChecker = FinalEncryptedPass.LastIndexOf(toFind); //grab another instance of, and store as an integer value, the index of where that repeat character is- 

            while (RepeatChecker != -1)                         // If the value 'RepeatChecker' is 'null'/ or -1, we know that there was no repeat of the value we just changed a second ago-                   -1-^
            {
                string integerToCountBy = RepeatChecker.ToString();
                AccountableToRepeats.Add(integerToCountBy); // should add a zero at the first repeat-
                string toFind2 = toFind.ToString();        //  Convert "the 'char' in question" to string so we can add to the string list ( AccountabletoRepeats )
                AccountableToRepeats.Add(toFind2);        //   ex. the password 'Reed23' would have the following stored in
                                                          //    AccountableToRepeats -list (ignoring encryption): AccountableToRepeats["0",1,"E",E"] before the while=looop ends.
                                                          //count = count++;// doesn't work.. just keep them in some order and replace the squiggles. 
                                                          // squiggle has to be a char first to go into stringbuilder below (just like 'fromOmega' (in the instance of "none-repeating characters"))
                sb[RepeatChecker] = squiggle[0];
                FinalEncryptedPass = sb.ToString();
                RepeatChecker = FinalEncryptedPass.LastIndexOf(toFind);    //check for another repeat of the same character (stored in 'toFind' variable)      // ----------------------+
            }
            PasswordLength = PasswordLength - 1;
            count = count+ 1;
        }
        return sb.ToString();

    }
```

The method is essentially supposed to use chars at specific indexes of the variables ( IndexAlpha, IndexOmega, and EncryptionCharLibrary ) from an 'Indexers' object ( UsingIndexes), however!!, when I run, I get an error within the 'Indexes.cs' class saying, exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' was thrown..

It sounds like, in my words, "the first variable in the Indexes.cs class is being declared until the-end-of-time".. I'm trying to reform my literally savage procedural programming ways, by essentially shuffling the code you see above over and I'm not sure if it's appropriate to be calling an object of a class within the method of another class? is that what I did wrong?

idts.. Very appreciative of any help ( I had NOT had any issues with 'Indexes.cs' throwing the overflow error until I had input the Person's method, (by it's christian name: 'InitialEncryptionComputationAndRepeatTracker()' ).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we (community) can not help you to find a bug. We can only give you an advice, how to debug this kind of problem. What you are sure, this is the method where the `StackOverflowException` was thrown, place a breakpoint on the first line of the function. Once the application breaks, try to step each function *(or to simply it, press again F5)*. The breakpoint should stop the application again. Then see stack trace to which function calls this function from within it and fix recursion.

Comment: `int   count = ForMethod.ComputeOddEven();` What does this method return?

Comment: @Sumitraj it returns a '3' or a '2'. I check if the value is divisible or not and, whether or not it is, will change which "index string" I use to start the "encryption".

Comment: @Julo Gotchya. I'll give that a shot. (in 2 days it'll let me mark that below answer as a the final answer )

Comment: Yea. I just realized there is a little call stack window where you can click to the breaking point. It's right when the Indexes object is declared within Person.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Julo pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927246/calling-another-classs-property-within-a-particular-classs-method-causing-an-o#comment94696525_53927246),

> this is the method where the StackOverflowException was thrown, place a breakpoint on the first line of the function. Once the application breaks, try to step each function (or to simply it, press again F5). The breakpoint should stop the application again. Then see stack trace to which function calls this function from within it and fix recursion.